# Programmes at how close?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

please help to fix the script.

```
import tkinter
import sys


class Operations():
    def openFile():
        pass

    def question(self, title, text, *args):
        return tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title, text)

    def quitter(self, parent):
        print('check')
        ans = self.question('Verify quit', 'Are you sure you want to quit?')
        if ans:
            tkinter.Frame.quit(self)


class ToolBar(Operations, tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent  
        self.makeToolBar()

    def makeToolBar(self):
        frame = tkinter.Frame(self.parent)
        frame.pack(side = 'top', fill = 'x', expand = 'yes')

        tool1 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'New')
        tool1.pack(side = 'left')

        tool2 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Open')
        tool2.pack(side = 'left')

        tool3 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Save')
        tool3.pack(side = 'left')

        tool4 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Close')
        tool4.pack(side = 'left')

        tool5 = tkinter.Button(frame, text = 'Quit', command = lambda: self.quitter(root))
        tool5.pack(side = 'right')        



root = tkinter.Tk()
toolBar = ToolBar(root)
root.mainloop()
```

if I run the script from IDLE environment and push the button "Quit", then in the console displays "check".

if I run the script in windows7 via double click on the file (myfile.py), and then click on the button "Quit", then in the console output:

> File "C:\Python33\projects\TEXTPADS\textPad_OOP\q.py", line 14
>       ans = self.question('Verify quit', 'Are you sure you want to   File "C:\Python33\projects\TEXTPADS\textPad_OOP\q.py", line 10
>       return tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(title, text) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'messagebox'

I need to after clicking on the "Quit" button occurred closing program

Comment: Seems like your IDLE is using a different version of Python. Try adding `import sys; print(sys.version)` to your script and see what that prints in both cases.

Comment: on IDLE:Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
on cmd: none

Comment: C:\Users\1>python --version 
Python 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's causing the problem, but I can reproduce the exact same behaviour on Linux (Xubuntu 13.10, Python 3.3.2+), too.

Adding `print(tkinter.__file__)` shows that both `idle3` and `python3` are using the same `tkinter` lib, but `print(dir(tkinter))` shows that one indeed has the `messagebox` sub-module and one hasn't.

For me, adding `import tkinter.messagebox` to the imports solved the problem and the message box is shown both when started from `idle3` and from `python3` (i.e., from console).